# React App build folder showing date modified 1985

Tags: reactjs

I've never seen this before, is it corrupted data? My build folder for a react app I am deploying is showing this for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrSX0.png)
The date modified for the robot.txt file is saying 1985.

Comment: It's only metadata. If things work, it's not worth thinking about.